# Avoiding Simple Features message in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm not sure if this is a bug in sf but I can not get sf initial message to not show in Rmarkdown. I've used every command I know to try and silence the response:

````
```{r echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE, results=FALSE, warning=FALSE, comment=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
````

Does not prevent this message in Rmarkdown

```
Simple feature collection with 10 features and 9 fields
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -80.13852 ymin: 39.65424 xmax: -75.20251 ymax: 42.18098
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

And adding the comment=FALSE line actually adds the word "FALSE" to every line

```
FALSE Simple feature collection with 10 features and 8 fields
FALSE geometry type:  POLYGON
FALSE dimension:      XY
FALSE bbox:           xmin: -8920979 ymin: 4815823 xmax: -8371505 ymax: 5188128
FALSE epsg (SRID):    3857
FALSE proj4string:    +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs
```

Comment: Add `message=FALSE` and you should be good to go.

Comment: It still shows up when I add that.

Comment: Then it's possible that whatever package produces the output is using `print` or `cat` to do this.

Comment: Does that mean there is no way to silence the message?

Comment: There are questions on SO about this. I think the recommended method is to wrap the call in `sink` or `capture.output`.

Comment: Ahh OK, I fount this in another SO question.  I need to use `invisible(capture.output(*code*))` to silence the ouput, thanks Imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `invisible(capture.output(*code*))` to silence a simple feature's output.